# How to create a Team Project in TFS from a mac machine?

Tags: version-control, git, visual-studio, tfs, macos

I am on a mac machine and I'm planning to connect to a TFS git source control, I have a collection under the companies' TFS server, but I'm unable to create team projects in order to push my code to.

I have tried the following:

- Team Explorer Everywhere ( Eclipse plugin ), doesn't have the add feature
- Team Explorer web access

Is there a way to achieve this without having visual studio and a windows machine ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using a 3rd party tool and not about a conceptual programming question.

Answer (score 3):

Regrettably, no.  Team Project Creation involves many steps and includes things like setting up SQL Reporting Services and a Sharepoint site, the clients for which only exist on Windows.

To create a new Team Project on an on-premises Team Foundation Server installation, you will need to use Visual Studio on Windows.  (Note that this is not true for Visual Studio Online, though, which allows you to create a new Team Project on the web, since it does not support SQL Reporting Services or Sharepoint).